# Angular routes to root of the server

Tags: angular, routes, single-sign-on

My app has following route configuration:

```
const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },    // if unauthenticated, goes to LoginComponent
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } 
];
```

And the urls are:
**local env**
localhost:4200
**SIT**
sit.company.com
**UAT**
uat.company.com
**PRODUCTION**
company.com

My app has Single-Sign On(SSO) feature using IBM WebSEAL so that when user first visits sit.company.com or uat.company.com or company.com, he will be redirected to login page provided by our other team for authentication.

While in my local environment, since no such SSO feature implemented, so user will be redirected to the LoginComponent for authentication.

**My problem is that I have two places where I try to route to the SSO page of the server like below.
However, it only goes back to LoginComponent, but never be able to go back to the SSO page of sit.company.com or uat.company.com or company.com. How to resolve that?**

**login.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (environment.production) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);  // route to server's root page for SSO login
    }
}

  onSignIn() {
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(this.username)) {
      this.loginSub = this.authenticateService.login(this.username)
        .subscribe(user => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        });
    }
  }

  onSignOut() {
    this.authenticateService.logout();
  }
```

**authentication-guard.ts**

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticateService.isAuthenticatedWithBackend()
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          const userDetails: UserDetails = {
            userId: user.username,
            username: user.uacUser.userName
          };

          if (userDetails) {
            this.authenticateService.setCurrentUser(userDetails);
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }
        }),
        catchError(e => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return of(false);
        })
      );
  }
```

**abc-page.component.html**

```
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="'/'">root page</a>
```

p.s. I'm using Angular 9

Comment: can you add more detail about login component, home component and authguard here?

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy, I added the code snippets in the post. Thanks.

Comment: @Angus  this.router.navigate(['/']) will always go to home component which have a authguard which will redirect to login, but in login component you have a redirect back to home (if env is prod) there you have to check whether user is authenticated or not.

Comment: @laiju, but I'm not sure how to implement to navigate to root of the application (i.e. sit.company.com or uat.company.com or company.com) if I'm not using this.router.navigate(['/']).

Comment: @Angus Can u explain the requirement little more clearly. In order to access the route of the website (home) the user need to be authenticated right? And the authentication is done in login component. Am I right?

Comment: @laiju, yes you are right. The complexity is that in the non-local environment (SIT/UAT/PRD), pre-authentication is actually done by IBM WebSEAL SSO layer prior to acceessing to my app server, so you can say there is no authentication in my own app actually in that environment.

Comment: @laiju, However, in my local environment, there is no such SSO layer, but I still need to make a login page which is used to test with different login user profile. That's why I used "if (environment.production) {...}" to distinguish between non-local and local environment and hence redirect to root of server ("/") or my own LoginComponent.